# How to add extra column mysql database table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am new in Django . I am using Mysql database for my django project.I have created model class in models.py.

in my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class AuthModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

i have Migrated this Fields into my Mysql Database using following commands

```
 Python manage.py makemigrations  
 Python manage.py migrate
```

which is making table in my database as shown in below
[image]

now, i want  to add one more column in  table which is "user_type".
 i can add "user_type" column manually from database but its not inserting "user_type" value into table. because i have not include "user_type" column in  my 'AuthModel'.
if i include user_type into 'AuthModel' and  run migration commands ,however its not working . i want to add user_type column in to my table. how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new field to your model and rerun migration commands:

```
class AuthModel(models.Model):
     # ...
     user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255) # or whatever field you want
```

then rerun:

```
Python manage.py makemigrations  
Python manage.py migrate
```

And your database will have the new `user_type` column.

Answer (score 1):

First you should add the field in **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class AuthModel(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and then change in **admin.py**
by adding field name as you declare in **models.py**
like-

```
class UAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    dics = ('user_type')
```

and if you have any **form** file then change add it in also ,
then go to terminal and -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If terminal says-

```
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Then press 1 and provide a value.

And your database will have new  'user_type' column.